# Is this picture of relativity correct?

Tags: general-relativity, forces, gravity

Can forces be said to exist in a real sense in general relativity?

Comment: Please note, that check my work kind of question are usually discouraged.

Comment: to me, rephrasing a physical explaination and submitting it for review is quite a good way to do. It's not like giving 3 pages of equation and asking us to check.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

General Relativity says that a massive object changes the concept of "straight line" in the region around it.  There is no "force" involved.

The apple, or the Moon, moves in a "straight line", knowing nothing of the Earth.  It's just that Earth surreptitiously changed space (space-time) so that all "straight lines" in the region curve inwards towards Earth.

Of course, it's a lot more complicated, but the general idea is as above.